# What is the best way to differentiate between two methods going to same view controller?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

This is a little complicated, but here is what I need to accomplish.
Basically, I have a ViewController that has two buttons (login and upload video button) that both goes to a login ViewController. However, when a user clicks on the upload video button and then the user signs in they need to be redirected to a third ViewController called  uploadVideoViewController. Where as the user clicks on the login button ,he doesn't need to be redirected anywhere. Is there a way to differentiate between the two buttons so I can properly redirect the user when I need to?

ViewController

```
-(IBAction)uploadVideo:(id)sender
{
    [self loginViewController];
}

-(IBAction)login:(id)sender
{
    [self loginViewController];
}
```

LoginViewController

```
-(void)login 
{
    if (uploadVideobuttonclicked) {
       [self uploadViewController];
    } else {
        //do nothing
    }
}
```

Comment: please next time use a sane code formatting.

Comment: How do you load the view controller? Are you using a segue?

Comment: Could you post the [self loginViewController]; code?

Answer (score 1):

I would use a custom initializer for your view controller.
It would help if you could show the loginViewController method.

But I would do something like

```
[self loginViewControllerWithVideo:YES];
```

then when the 2nd view loads you can check for that bool and simply load the next view.

You could even go one step further and include the video instead of a bool value.

```
[self loginViewControllerWithVideo:videoToUpload];
```

Putting this together here is an example based on your code. Note that I removed self. I don't think self would be necessary in this case. If you need an example for the initializer let me know.

```
-(IBAction)uploadVideo:(id)sender
{
    [loginViewController loginViewControllerWithVideo:videoToUpload];
}

-(IBAction)login:(id)sender
{
    [loginViewController loginViewControllerWithVideo:nil];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a BOOL parameter to `-(void) login` method and pass TRUE/FALSE from two different places.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to show an alternative design for the solution to your problem. The issue I see with your current design is that you are coupling the upload action and the login action too tightly. What if in the future you add another button that also requires login? You end up with a huge `if` and, what is worse, your `loginViewController` knows too much: It knows about an `uploadViewController`, when it shouldn't. It's only responsibility should be to log the user in, nothing more. We can use delegation to make your design more clean and extensible.

First, define a simple delegate to communicate your view controllers:

```
@protocol LoginDelegate <NSObject>
- (void)didEndLogin;
@end
```

Then, in your main view controller:

```
-(IBAction)uploadVideo:(id)sender
{
    [self.uploadViewController upload];
}

-(IBAction)login:(id)sender
{
    [self.loginViewController login];
}
```

Then, include the login logic in `UploadViewController`:

```
@class UploadViewController<LoginDelegate>

- (void)upload
{
    if (user is not logged in) {
        LoginViewController *loginViewController = [LoginViewController alloc] init...];
        loginViewController.delegate = self;
        // You can present this view controller as you like
        [self presentViewController:loginViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
    } else {
        // Upload
    }
}

- (void)didEndLogin
{
    // Upload
}
```

In your `loginViewController`, declare the delegate and call it after login is complete:

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) id<LoginDelegate> delegate;

- (void)login
{
    ...
    [self.delegate didEndLogin];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it just me but why didn't anyone suggest adding a tag to a UIButton. That way you know which button was pressed ... unless I missed OPs question.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
   UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
   button.tag = 500;

   [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (IBAction)login:(id)sender {

   if ([sender tag] == 500) {
        // do something
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a property to `loginViewController`
`@property(nonatomic) BOOL uploadButtonPressedInVC;`
Now when you are navigating to `loginViewController` set that property.

```
-(IBAction)uploadVideo:(id)sender
{    LoginViewController *lVC=[[LoginViewController alloc]init];
     lVC.uploadButtonPressedInVC=YES;
    [self loginViewController];

}

-(IBAction)login:(id)sender
{
     LoginViewController *lVC=[[LoginViewController alloc]init];
     lVC.uploadButtonPressedInVC=YES;
    [self loginViewController];
}
```

Or you can create LoginViewController object in your method definition.

Answer (score -3):

This might help you:

ViewController

```
-(IBAction)uploadVideo:(id)sender
{
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKye:@"Video_To_Upload"];

    [self loginViewController];
}

-(IBAction)login:(id)sender
{
   [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:NO forKye:@"Video_To_Upload"];

   [self loginViewController];
}
```

LoginViewController

```
-(void)login 
{
    BOOL uploadVideobuttonclicked = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]  boolForKey@"Video_To_Upload"];
    if (uploadVideobuttonclicked) {
       [self uploadViewController];
   } else {
      //do nothing
   }
}
```

Comment: There is absolutely no need to introduce some kind of global variable for what he is trying to accomplish.

Comment: @sha But as per his requirement, the `login` method is in `SecondViewController`. So how would he able to do so using a local BOOL. I would love know an alternative. Thanks for suggestion.